# Cargo run / start not working, missing Ant dependency?

Tags: maven, ant, cargo

I've been trying to set up the cargo-maven2 plugin (although I am using Maven 3; and this is supposed to be ok) so that I can start a container during the pre-integration-test phase and shut it down in the post-integration test phase.

I'm having no luck.  I keep getting this error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:start (start-container) on project microgivr.web: Execution start-container of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:start failed: Unable to load the mojo 'start' in the plugin 'org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4'. A required class is missing: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildException
```

Easy fix, right?  Add Ant as a dependency.  So I add:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
<artifactId>ant</artifactId>
<version>1.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

(And lord only know why this should need Ant in the first place.)

I can now find org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException on my classpath, but I STILL get this error.

So, thinking this is surely some issue with my own build, I decided to start fresh, using the maven2-cargo-plugin archetype documented here: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Archetypes

You know what?  Same problem!

I've tried different versions of the plugin.  I've tried different versions of Ant.  No luck.

Someone MUST have run into this before.  I see mentions of this issue online, but don't see any solutions.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Damnit.  I guess I put the Ant dependency in the wrong spot.  That dependency needs to be expressed in the plugin's OWN  stanza; NOT with the rest of the dependencies.

So... moving it did the trick.

Comment: But still, you'd expect (or at least hope) that this dependency would be documented and that the archetype from the authors of the plugin would get it right.